Informatica Integration Sevice is unable to get restarted
We have informatica server running in Solaris. All of us sudden integration service was disconnected and we tried multiple times to restart with cli and portal and its not working.
We are not sure exactly what is the issue and impacted reason.
If any one can suggest how to go through i can add all the log information one by one to this request.
We have verified the Node logs and server logs and dont see any issue.
(Please do not down vote as i dont know what exact log i need to add in this request) If any one can suggest i will add all the information

which infa version?

can you pls check if you/anyone did any changes like - update firewall settings, patching,   update user settings, patched Solaris, space available or not. If all seems ok, try restarting whole domain, or OS.

Have you checked Admin Console log, Service Log tab? Integration Service write entry log in Administrator Console. Check it and share log messages. You can filter by Integration Service.

It seems this answer is asking for more information on the issue the OP is facing. In this case I'd suggest adding this as a comment to the question instead of an answer.
